# How can I cancel my residence visa without getting my employer involved?

Tags: visa, immigration, uae

This is to seek your assistance regarding a visa cancellation issue. I used to work for a company under Saifzone. I worked there only for couple of months then I had to go back to my homeland urgently due to severe health issues of my mother. Later I sent an email to my employer stating my resignation as it was not possible for me to continue working in the UAE.

After an year and half, I am planning to come back to UAE again, but I came to know that my employer didn't cancel my visa and will not help me get back. I would like to know if there is any other way to cancel my residence visa so that I can get a new visiting visa.

Comment: Have you asked at the UAE consulate?  Normally, for non-employment visas, you would deal directly with the consulate.  I suppose that they can also cancel your residence visa without your employer's participation.

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer, because I can't find verification, but my employer in the UAE was absolutely the only one who could cancel my work visa.  But there might be different types.